# Does MINUS QUERY validate each and Every record between the tables?

Tags: sql, db2

As far my knowledge , MINUS Query will not validate each and Every column data in a table. It will validate only the # of records is matching from source with # of records in target.

Let s say

Source is having 
10
20
30
Target is having 
10
40
30

Select Column A from Source MINUS Select Column from Target will give 0 as output. Since there is a single record mismatch will not give 1 as output. Right. Please clarify on this. I knew, but it was become a argument.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you are interested in *MINUS* made on the quantities of duplicates for unique rows, look for *MINUS ALL* or *EXCEPT ALL*. There is SO question asking for description of that clause https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432720/trying-to-understand-except-all-in-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it? It's fairly easy to test:

```
WITH

Source  (COL) AS (
    SELECT 10 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 20 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 30 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)

,Target (COL) AS (
    SELECT 10 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 40 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 30 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)

SELECT COL FROM Source 
    MINUS
SELECT COL FROM Target
```

As you can see from [the documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000877.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-5-2):

> **EXCEPT** or **EXCEPT ALL**
>       Derives a result table by combining two other result tables (R1 and R2). If EXCEPT ALL is specified, the result consists of all rows
>   that do not have a corresponding row in R2, where duplicate rows are
>   significant. If EXCEPT is specified without the ALL option, the result
>   consists of all rows that are only in R1, with duplicate rows in the
>   result of this operation eliminated.
>
> ```
> For compatibility with other SQL implementations, 
> MINUS can be specified as a synonym for EXCEPT.
> ```

Therefore, `EXCEPT` (or `MINUS`) will only return the rows from the first table that do not have a match in the second table. In this case, you will get `20` back.

Comment: You might also add an example showing how it'll remove _all_ matching rows from the first table.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are wrong. Here minus clause will return 20 as record.

For more info read this:- http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/7696.minus-clause.aspx